# Unable to apply relayout method to the chart, react-plotly.js

Tags: reactjs, plotly

I have created a barchart using react-ploty.js. I would like to change the width of the chart when an onClick event is performed on the bar, for which I am trying to using relayout method of Plotly to reset the width. But when I try to do so, it throws, **Uncaught ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined** error. 
The way I am creating plot is :

```
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';

<Plot
  data={this.prepData(this.state.chartData)}
  onClick={(data) => {this.chartRelayout();}
  type={'bar'}
  layout={layout}/>

chartRelayout () {
        console.log("Relayout called");
        Plotly.relayout({
            width: 0.5 * window.innerWidth
        });
    }
```

Am i missing any import? I even tried to do plot.relayout and get the same error for that too. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are missing an import,you havent imported `Plotly` nor referenced it in your current file thats why you are getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined

You imported only `Plot`

```
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';
```

Its detailed [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly-webpack) how to install [plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript/#fundamentals) for a webpack project hence giving you access to the `Plotly` object.

After following these [instructions](https://github.com/plotly/plotly-webpack) you would just.

```
import Plotly from 'plotly.js/dist/plotly'
```

**BUT** you can still achieve the resizing of the bars with the current `react-plotly.js` because its already calling the [Plotly.react](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyreact) function when

> One of data, layout or config has changed identity as checked via a shallow ===

Now all you have to do is define your layout data into your state, so that when we change the layout properties the Plot will be rendered again with the new layout properties.

Add the layout to the state.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { layout: {...}};
    }

chartRelayout () {
        this.setState({
           layout: {width: 0.5 * window.innerWidth}
        })
    }

<Plot
  data={this.prepData(this.state.chartData)}
  onClick={(data) => {this.chartRelayout();}
  type={'bar'}
  layout={this.state.layout}/>
```

This lets "react-plotly.js" handle the calls to the underlining "plotly.js" library as intended by the react-plotly.js library

Comment: If I have multiple attributes in layout that I don't want to update but only want to change width, the above solution will not work right ? In addition to the width, I will have to reset all other attributes too.

Comment: No , you dont have to reset other attributes."When you call setState(), React merges the object you provide into the current state" Since you are only providing the width in your setState function, only the width will change and everything else will not change thats in the state. read about it here [state-and-lifecycle.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in this file that gives context to the `Plotly` object, which is why it is undefined.

On line 2, try writing `import Plotly from 'plotly.js';`. Also, what does your `package.json` look like? Make sure you have installed both `react-plotly.js` and `plotly.js`: `$ npm install react-plotly.js plotly.js`.

These packages end in .js, so it's possible you missed adding that during the install process.